# Why is the partial derivative $f_x' = 0 $ is not continous?

Tags: multivariable-calculus, continuity, partial-derivative

Looking again at my first CalculusII exam and I get confused about something.

Let $  f(x, y) =
\begin{cases}
(x^2 + y^2) \sin\left(\frac{1}{x^2 + y^2}\right),  & \text{if $(x, y) \ne (0, 0)$} \\
0, & \text{if $(x, y) = (0, 0)$}  \\
\end{cases}$

> 1. Find the partial derivatives at $(0, 0)$.
> 2. Check whether $f'x(0, 0)$ and $f'_y(0, 0)$ continous at $(0, 0)$.

My answer was:

> 1. a. $$f'x(0, 0) = \lim_{h \to 0}\frac{f(0 + h, 0) - f(0, 0)}{h} = \frac{h^2\sin(\frac{1}{h^2})}{h} = h\sin(\frac{1}{h^2}) = h\cdot(\text{bounded}) = 0.$$
>
> b. $$f_y' = \lim_{h \to 0}\frac{h^2\sin(\frac{1}{h^2})}{h} = h(\text{bounded}) = 0.$$

Got full points.

My answer for $2$ was:

> $$\lim_{(x, y) \to (0, 0)}f'_y(x, y) = f'_y(0, 0) = 0$$
>
> $$\lim_{(x, y) \to (0, 0)}f'_x(x, y) = f'_x(0, 0) = 0$$
>
> > $\implies$ both partials are continous.

Here I've got $0$ out $4$ points.

What have I done wrong? Thanks in advance.

Comment: You need to compute $f_y(x,y)$. You only have its value at $(0,0)$. Find (using the usual differentiation rules) $f_y(x,y)$ and see if indeed your limit condition holds. (Similarly, for $f_x(x,y)$.)

Comment: Also, your work assumed exactly what you were asked to check.

Comment: @DavidMitra I remember that my teacher noted something similar. you are right, thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can compute $f_y'(x,y)$ directly:
$$f_y'(x,y) = 2y \sin \left(\frac{1}{x^2 + y^2} \right) - \cos \left( \frac{1}{x^2 + y^2} \right) \frac{2y}{x^2 + y^2}$$

Note that $f_y'(x,0) = 0$ but $f_y'(0,y) = 2y \sin \left( \frac{1}{y^2} \right) - \frac{2}{y} \cos \left( \frac{1}{y^2}\right)$ which is unbounded as $y \to 0$.